# Grails - project build system

Tags: java, grails, ant, build, web

Newbie question,

using it for web application. I'm looking for a tool that will help me build and deploy Grails apps (similar to Ant) for different environments, without loosing the "Edit > Save > Refresh" development style.

Comment: They are all built-in functionalitys, what do you mean "different environment"? you mean client-side, server-side, both?

Comment: I mean development vs production. for example in dev mode the password could be "1234" and in dev "DFG54^&HGFGV" but the variable code is the same ... something like pass="{properties.pass}";

Comment: ok, you like to have the edit>save>refresh on live-systems?

Comment: For production you'd be best advised to generate and deploy a WAR file. Just like other java webapps. See : http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/deployment.html

Comment: sure, the edita>save>refresh is only for the dev stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want variables by environment just add your properties like this:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
        grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
        grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = '/admin/dbconsole'
    }
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
}
```

Then get your variable like this:

```
${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}
```

To switch environment, use the following command:

```
grails run-app      // runs with the default "development" data source
grails dev run-app  // runs with the "development" data source
grails run-war // runs with the production data source
grails -Dgrails.env=mycustomenv run-app // specific a custom environment
grails test run-app // runs with the test data source
```

[Documentation](http://www.grails.org/Environments).

Comment: The Grails documentation does not recommend using the "grails run-app" command for production. See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/deployment.html

Comment: Thanks, edited to change to the recommended 'grails run-war' instead.

Comment: Is there a way to use different files rather than scoping style?